# How to get a block of number from snowflake sequence

Tags: sequence, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I see only this way to get sequence number.  but I want to get a block of them.
select seq1.nextval a from dual;

Comment: Use GETNEXTVAL ? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html  Show your context with some code

Comment: Can you add more context? What kind of block of numbers and for what purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a snowflake [generator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html) to generate rows and then use `seq.nextval` to get a block of sequences. I assume this is what you mean:

```sql
-- Create the sequence
create or replace sequence seq1;

-- Generate the block
select
    s.nextval
from table (generator(rowcount => 10)) v,
     table (getnextval(seq1)) s
order by 1;
```

Output of the above select:

```
+-------+
|NEXTVAL|
+-------+
|1      |
|2      |
|3      |
|4      |
|5      |
|6      |
|7      |
|8      |
|9      |
|10     |
+-------+
```

It's important to understand the [semantics of sequences](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#sequence-semantics). Sequences do not necessarily get generated sequentially (without gaps) as they have in this example but they will always be unique.

From the docs linked above:

> There is no guarantee that values from a sequence are contiguous (gap-free) or that the sequence values are assigned in a particular order. There is, in fact, no way to assign values from a sequence to rows in a specified order other than to use single-row statements (this still provides no guarantee about gaps).